# "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document" when debugging asp.net service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, breakpoints

I am designing an ASP.NET website, which also provides a WCF service for client applications to use. However, when I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the service's operation function, it shows the message in the title and hence I can't debug the operation. This is how I test it:
I first create an asp.net website project, which has the WCF service and the operation, I publish it in the local IIS server, I can browse the service's wsdl file from the browser, which I guess means the service is hosted correctly. I also put the

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

in the Web.config file to enable debug.

Then I create another test client console project to call the operation, the proxy class is generated using svcutil.exe. Then I attach the debug to w3wp.exe process. There is only one process because I am only using one application pool in IIS. Now when I start the client and call the operation, I can never hit the operation's function in the server. Could anyone tell me what's the problem? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out I was ignoring the debug information when I published the website to IIS, i.e., there is no .pdb file generated for the symbols for debug. How I fixed it is to check the "Emit debug information" option in the Publish Web Site dialog, and then the .pdb file will be generated and the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug your WCF service you can use the build in WCF test client that comes along with .NET framework(.NET v4.0) Just open the service page hit F5 to start debugging. An WCF Test client should fire up and you can invoke the required operation and debug it. Just make sure that your project builds in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am not sure if I understand your solution. For one thing, my service requires some customized input as parameters, so the build in client might not be a good choice to control the service.